# Save and retrive rtf text from database using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database

I just finished to save a text from a richtextbox into sql database. Here you have the code:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MARIA-PC;Initial Catalog=Account;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[FISIER] (File_name,The_text) VALUES (@File_name,@The_text)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@File_name", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@The_text", richTextBox1.Rtf);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Here is the table [Click here for table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te3D0.jpg)

Now, my problem is that I don't know how to retrive the text from the database. As you see there the text I had saved into `The_text` and the data type is `Text`. I want to retrive the data back into richtextbox.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search would have revealed the answer to this. For example, here is some sample code that queries a database table...

```
// 1. Instantiate a new command with a query and connection
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select CategoryName from Categories", conn);

// 2. Call Execute reader to get query results
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

You can change the table name and fields to match your database.

This code was found at http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson03, but there are millions of other sites that will teach you this stuff.